# How do I get this main() to work with my encoder()?

Tags: python, function, encryption

Right now it's not running the function on each letter in the sentence and then printing out the result.

```
#secret code encryptor 

def encoder(plain):

    for i in plain:
        i=ord(i)*77+4
        return i 

def main():

    plain=input('Enter a sentence: ')
    final=encoder(plain)
    print(final)

main()
```

Comment: it's because you return on the first iteration of the for-loop

Comment: You may consider `yield`ing each result of the `for` loop.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: yeah, teaching someone right at the start of programming about generators is perhaps not the best idea?

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, which is why I didn't answer with it

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect all converted characters in your function in a list, and return that:

```
def encoder(plain):
    result = []  

    for i in plain:
        i=ord(i)*77+4
        result.append(i)

    return result
```

`return` exits the function immediately, so your version only returns the *first* encoded value.

Comment: he probably also needs to return string, not a list. that is needs to know `''.join()` method.

Comment: @alko: the OP has asked a progression of questions; we'll worry about turning these values back to strings at another time.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `encoder`:

```
def encoder(plain):

for i in plain:
    i=ord(i)*77+4
    return i
```

You should realize that when the return statement is executed, the execution of `encoder` ends right away. The body of the loop is never executed even twice! So you will want to move that return statement if you want your for loop to actually iterate through all the numbers. After that, you might run into another problem resulting from i being overwritten each round, so you will have to rethink how you construct your return value altogether.